# PowerMock: mocking of static methods (+ return original values in some particular methods)

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock

I use PowerMock 1.4.7 and JUnit 4.8.2

I need to mock only some static methods and I want others (from the
same class) just to return original value.
When I mock with `mockStatic` and don't call `when().doReturn()` all
static methods return their defaults - like null when returning Object
or false when returning boolean...etc. So I try to use
`thenCallRealMethod` explicitly on each static method to return
default implementation (means no mocking/ no fakes) but I don't know
how to call it on every possible arguments variations (= I want for every possible input call original method). I only know how to mock concrete argument variation.

Comment: Best answer and useful one https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito/stub

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use a spy on your static class and mock only specific methods:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyStaticTest.MyStaticClass.class)
public class MyStaticTest {

public static class MyStaticClass {
    public static String getA(String a) {
        return a;
    }
    public static String getB(String b) {
        return b;
    }
}

@Test
public void should_partial_mock_static_class() throws Exception {
    //given
    PowerMockito.spy(MyStaticClass.class);
    given(MyStaticClass.getB(Mockito.anyString())).willReturn("B");
    //then
    assertEquals("A", MyStaticClass.getA("A"));
    assertEquals("B", MyStaticClass.getA("B"));
    assertEquals("C", MyStaticClass.getA("C"));
    assertEquals("B", MyStaticClass.getB("A"));
    assertEquals("B", MyStaticClass.getB("B"));
    assertEquals("B", MyStaticClass.getB("C"));
}

}
```

Comment: Although this works, be careful when using matcher arguments. If you were to use _Mockito.any()_ and you're trying to stub a spy's method, the actual getB() impl is invoked during the evaluation of the stubbing statement. If getB() fails to handle null arguments, a NPE will be thrown.

Comment: what is "given"?

Comment: This did not work for me.  I had to replace .spy(..) with PowerMockito.mockStatic(...) to get it working; which refutes the authors intended solution.

Comment: This didn't work for me, even through multiple iterations, even with @LucianovanderVeekens comments.  More explanation please?

Answer (score 18):

You can also use the stubbing API:

```
stub(method(MyStaticClass.class, "getB")).toReturn("B");
```

Edit:

To use `stub` and `method` statically import methods from these packages:

1. `org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier`
2. `org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher`

For more info refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior)

Comment: This approach worked for me, but the answer from denis.solonenko did not. It's hard to understand when to use doReturn, when, given, and stub, which all claim to do about the same thing. Each works sometimes and not others

Comment: This approach worked for me while doing partial mocking with Static class.

Comment: Thanks, please add `stub` method scope

Comment: How do you use this? Can you please provide the entire code example.

Comment: I've added instructions on which packages to statically import methods from now

Comment: One problem with this approach is, I cant say for e.g: if my first argument is "abc": stub(method(MyStaticClass.class, "getB", "abc")).toReturn("B"); It does not work

Answer (score 1):

I managed to use `spy` and `doReturn` to achieve it.

```
class MyStatic {
    static String foo() { return "foo"; }
    static String foobar() { return foo() + "bar"; }
}

@Test
public void thisShouldSpyStaticMethods() {
    // arrange
    spy(MyStatic.class);
    doReturn("mocked foo").when(MyStatic.class);
    MyStatic.foo();

    // act
    final String result = MyStatic.foobar();

    // assert
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo("mocked foobar");
}
```

The `doReturn` followed by a call to the method to be mocked looks weird (at least to me), but seems to do the trick.

Using `spy` with `when(MyStatic.foo()).thenReturn("mocked foo")` doesn't work for me.

PowerMockito's documentation on [mocking static method](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito#mocking-static-method).

Comment: While this works, it doesn't work for multiple static methods inside one method call.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this question [PowerMockito mock single static method and return object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583202/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object)

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyStaticClass.class);
```

alone does not mock all methods (in recent versions of PowerMockito at least), only enables mocking later of individual methods.