# How do I mock Class<? extends List> myVar in Mockito?

Tags: class, mocking, mockito, powermock

I want to mock a Class in Mockito.  It will then have a .newInstance() call issued which will be expected to return an actual class instance (and will return a mock in my case).

If it was setup correctly then I could do:

```
ArrayList myListMock = mock(ArrayList.class);
when(myVar.newInstance()).thenReturn(myListMock);
```

I know I can set it up so that a new instance of class ArrayList will be a mock (using PowerMockito whenNew), just wondering if there was a way to mock this kind of a class object so I don't have to override instance creation...

Below is the real class I'm trying to mock, I can't change the structure it is defined by the interface.  What I'm looking for is a way to provide cvs when initialize is called.

```
public class InputConstraintValidator 
    implements ConstraintValidator<InputValidation, StringWrapper> {

    Class<? extends SafeString> cvs;

    public void initialize(InputValidation constraintAnnotation) {
        cvs = constraintAnnotation.inputValidator();
    }

    public boolean isValid(StringWrapper value, 
                   ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        SafeString instance;
        try {
             instance = cvs.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mockito is designed exclusively for mocking *instances* of objects. Under the hood, the mock method actually creates a proxy that receives calls to all non-final methods, and logs and stubs those calls as needed. *There's no good way to use Mockito to replace a function on the Class object itself.* This leaves you with a few options:

1. I don't have experience with PowerMock but it seems it's [designed for mocking static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10652564/1426891).
2. In dependency-injection style, make your static factory method into a factory instance. Since it looks like you're not actually working with `ArrayList`, let's say your class is `FooBar` instead:

   ```
   class FooBar {
     static class Factory {
       static FooBar instance;
       FooBar getInstance() {
         if (instance == null) {
           instance = new FooBar();
         }
         return instance;
       }
     }
     // ...
   }
   ```

   Now your class user can receive a `new FooBar.Factory()` parameter, which creates your real FooBar in singleton style (hopefully [better and more threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71399/1426891) than my simple implementation), and you can use pure Mockito to mock the Factory. If this looks like it's a lot of boilerplate, it's because it is, but if you are thinking of switching to a DI solution like [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) you can cut down a lot of it.
3. Consider making a field or method package-private or protected and documenting that it's [visible for testing purposes](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html). Then you can insert a mocked instance in test code only.

   ```
   public class InputConstraintValidator implements 
       ConstraintValidator<InputValidation, StringWrapper> {
     Class<? extends SafeString> cvs;

     public void initialize(InputValidation constraintAnnotation) {
       cvs = constraintAnnotation.inputValidator();
     }

     public boolean isValid(StringWrapper value,
         ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
       SafeString instance;
       try {
         instance = getCvsInstance();
       } catch (InstantiationException e) {
         return false;
       } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
         return false;
       }
     }

     @VisibleForTesting protected getCvsInstance()
         throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
       return cvs.newInstance();
     }
   }

   public class InputConstaintValidatorTest {
     @Test public void testWithMockCvs() {
       final SafeString cvs = mock(SafeString.class);
       InputConstraintValidator validator = new InputConstraintValidator() {
         @Override protected getCvsInstance() {
           return cvs;
         }
       }
       // test
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: After a couple of months experience, I can say that I'm using PowerMock to mock instance creation and it's pretty easy and straight forward.

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to introduce an additional mock for `Class`:

```
ArrayList<?> myListMock = mock(ArrayList.class);
Class<ArrayList> clazz = mock(Class.class);
when(clazz.newInstance()).thenReturn(myListMock);
```

Of course the trick is making sure your mocked `clazz.newInstance()` doesn't end up getting called all over the place because due to type-erasure you can't specify that it's actually a `Class<ArrayList>`.

Also, be careful defining your own mock for something as fundamental as `ArrayList` - generally I'd use a "real one" and populate it with mocks.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't compile... maybe I missed something, I'll give it another go.