# Count method invocation of method variable instance

Tags: java, count, mocking, method-invocation

I have some code like this:

```
class FooBar {
    private String stateFoo;

    public FooBar(String stateFoo){
        this.stateFoo = stateFoo;
    }        

    public void foo() {
        FooInst f = FooInstFactory.createSomeFooInst(AnotherStaticFooConfig.getSomePath);
        f.justCountMe();
    }
}
```

My goal is to make sure that `f.justCountMe()` was executed exactly once. I know how to do it in general with mockito.
What I don't know is how do I inject a mocked version of `FooInst` into the `foo` method? So that I can count the invocation?

Is it even possible to do so?

Comment: Just to be sure: this is for testing only?

Comment: Yes, this is for testing only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible; I suggest to avoid using mocking libraries that temper with static fields (in the way PowerMock/Mockito do) - as it often comes with undesired side effects (for example many "coverage" tools produce invalid results when static mocking takes places).

So my suggestion: re-design your class under test. Instead of fetching f from a static factory; provide a constructor for either the factory or f; then you can mock the corresponding object; without the need to turn to the mighty but dangerous "Powerxyz" stuff.

Comment: I was thinking about this approach too, however, I always hesitate to change "production" code for better testing abilities.

Comment: @sveri That is why I try to do TDD (test driven development). I try to write test cases before, or at least "at the same" time when writing new production code. And I find so often that "hard to test" equals to "design is worth improving".

Answer (score 2):

You need to use powermockito and mock static method. See explanation how to do this here

[PowerMockito mock single static method and return object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583202/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object)