# How to use powerMockito to mock the static class

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassWithStatics.class})
public class mockTest  {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassWithStatics.class);
           PowerMockito.when(ClassWithStatics.getString()).thenReturn("999");

    System.out.println("String: " + ClassWithStatics.getString());
    }
```

```
FAILED: test
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when(PowerMockito.java:495)
at com.autoTest.servicetest.mockTest.test(mockTest.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you at least tried to follow the example in the exception message with `doReturn`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your test code. Show your `ClassWithStatics`.

Comment: The code 
    public class ClassWithStatics {
     
     public static String getString() {
      return "111";
     }
     
     public static int getInt() {
      return 1;
     }
    
    }

Comment: I take it that is post is based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583202/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object ?

Comment: And my powermock is 1.6.3，junit is 4.12

Comment: Mockito version? This works for me with powermock 1.6.2 and mockito 1.10.19..