# Trying to Mock a final class

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

Ive been trying to mock a final class(Paths)

```
@Test
public void testShouldCheckIfThereAreAnyChangesInTheFolder() throws Exception {
    Paths paths = PowerMockito.mock(Paths.class);
    Mockito.when(Paths.get("test/test/test")).thenReturn(path);

    fileSystem = path.getFileSystem();
    WatchService watchService = fileSystem.newWatchService();
    fileWatcher = new FileWatcher(path, fileSystem, watchService);

    fileWatcher.listenToFolderChanges();


}
```

But I keep getting this error

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

I don't want to do a Paths.get() of the actual path because the test keeps on hanging because its listening to the actual class

Comment: Try PowerMockito.when() instead of Mockito.when()

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583202/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object as you are using static method.

Comment: Thank you I managed to get it right.