# Mockito - test method inside a nethod

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I'm trying to test my Utils class. Some of the methods use other class methods. I want to mock the internal methods use so the test will assume they work (in order to make it real Unit test, which test the specific method).

I want to test 'buildUrl' method:

```
 public static String buildUrl(String path, List<Pair> queryParams, DateFormat dateFormat) {
    final StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
    url.append(path);

    if (queryParams != null && !queryParams.isEmpty()) {
        // support (constant) query string in `path`, e.g. "/posts?draft=1"
        String prefix = path.contains("?") ? "&" : "?";
        for (Pair param : queryParams) {
            if (param.getValue() != null) {
                if (prefix != null) {
                    url.append(prefix);
                    prefix = null;
                } else {
                    url.append("&");
                }
                String value = Utils.parameterToString(param.getValue(), dateFormat);
                url.append(Utils.escapeString(param.getName())).append("=").append(Utils.escapeString(value));
            }
        }
    }

    return url.toString();
}
```

BuildUrl uses 'parameterToString' (and others) which I want to mock for the test. So I tried something like this:

```
 @Test
public void testBuildUrl(){
    Utils util = new Utils();
    Utils utilSpy = Mockito.spy(util);
    Mockito.when(utilSpy.parameterToString("value1",new RFC3339DateFormat())).thenReturn("value1");
    List<Pair> queryParams = new ArrayList<Pair>();
    queryParams.add(new Pair("key1","value1"));
    String myUrl = utilSpy.buildUrl("this/is/my/path", queryParams, new RFC3339DateFormat());
    assertEquals("this/is/my/path?key1=value1&key2=value2", myUrl);
}
```

But I'm getting `MissingMethodInvocationException` from Mockito.
So my question is actually - how to mock a method that has been invoked within the tested method, and what's wrong with my test. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock / spy static invocations using standard Mockito.

You will have to use Powermockito and something to the following:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Utils.class)    
public class MyClassTest{

    @Test
    public void testBuildUrl(){
         PowerMockito.mockStatic(Utils.class);

         // mock the static method to return certain values
         Mockito.when(Utils.parameterToString("value1",new RFC3339DateFormat()))
             .thenReturn("value1");
         Mockito.when(Utils.escapeString(anyString()).thenReturn(desiredResult);

       // rest of test code
    }
```

Here is some more stuff to read through -> [powermockito static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583202/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to mock the internal methods use so the test will assume they work (in order to make it real Unit test, which test the specific method).

UnitTests do **not** test *specific method*s.

UnitTests test *public observable behavior* of the code under test.

---

If you feel you should mock some of the methods this could be a sign that your design needs improvement. There is no need to make utility methods `static` and maybe your Class under test has to much responsibilities.

Of cause *PowerMock* will overcome the problems in your test but IMHO the use of PowerMock is a surrender to bad design.