# How to ignore a toast in JUnit tests?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I want to test a method in a fragment but in this method I call a Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.signs), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Now I want to test the method with JUnit and Powermockito. For this I want to ignore the Toast. I tried it like this: mock the Toast and ignor toast.show()

```
Toast toastMock = mock(Toast.class);
doReturn(toastMock).when(Toast.makeText(any(Activity.class), anyString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT));
doNothing().when(toastMock).show();
```

But I always get a RuntimeException, because I call Toast without creating a new toast object. How can I bypass this problem?

Comment: can you add full test case? with PowerMockito setup as well

Comment: You're trying to mock a static method, you'll either have to wrap the static call into a non-static class which you can then mock, or mock the static method for which you can find help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583202/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object

Answer (score 0):

Write external class with method responsible for showing `Toast`, inject it to a `fragment` and mock this class behaviour. It might be a static method, as you use `PowerMockito`.

How to inject? Use [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) or [Toothpick](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/toothpick).