# How to provide object inside public method to access another method within it using PowerMock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I am writing unit test case for a Class

```
public class CurrentMoreInfoDataProvider implements CurrentMoreInfoInterface.presenterToModel{

private CurrentMoreInfoInterface.modelToPresenter modelToPresenter;

public CurrentMoreInfoDataProvider(CurrentMoreInfoInterface.modelToPresenter modelToPresenter) {
    this.modelToPresenter = modelToPresenter;
}

@Override
public void provideData() {
    WeatherApiResponsePojo apiWeatherData = WeatherDataSingleton.getInstance().getApiWeatherData();
    if(null != apiWeatherData.getCurrently()){
        CurrentlyPojo currently = apiWeatherData.getCurrently();
        if(null != currently){
            populateWeatherData(currently);
        }
    }
}

public void populateWeatherData(CurrentlyPojo currently) {....}
```

I want to just use verify method of power mock to test whether populateWeatherData get executed or not. Below is my test case so far.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(CurrentMoreInfoDataProvider.class)
public class TestCurrentMoreInfoDataProvider {

    private CurrentMoreInfoDataProvider dataProvider;
    @Mock
    CurrentMoreInfoInterface.modelToPresenter modelToPresenter;

    private CurrentlyPojo currentlyPojo = new CurrentlyPojo();
    @Test
    public void testPopulateWeatherData(){

        dataProvider = PowerMockito.spy(new CurrentMoreInfoDataProvider(modelToPresenter));
        dataProvider.provideData();
        Mockito.verify(dataProvider).populateWeatherData(currentlyPojo);
    }
}
```

If I run this I get null pointer exception in provideData method at

```
if(null != apiWeatherData.getCurrently()){
```

**How should I provide apiWeatherData to provideData method in that class?**

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583202/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object) to mock a static method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mock `WeatherDataSingleton.getInstance().getApiWeatherData()` too.

This would be much easier if you would not use static access in general and the Singelton pattern in particular.

---

> I tried mocking it, but how should i provide that mock object to provideData() ?

1. create a mock of `WeatherDataSingleton`.
2. Configure your Test so that this mock is used (by properly using *dependency injection* or by surrendering to your bad design using  Powermock).
3. configure the mock to return the data:

   ```
   doReturn(currentlyPojo).when(weatherDataSingletonMock).getApiWeatherData();
   ```

This resolves the NPE.

Comment: I tried mocking it, but how should i provide that mock object to provideData() ?

Comment: you are correct about the bad design part, I guess, have to redesign the code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Swapnil would you consider accepting/upvoting the answers that helped you

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need to go for PowerMockito if you apply a simple refactor to your production code:

```
public class CurrentMoreInfoDataProvider{

@Override
public void provideData() {
    WeatherApiResponsePojo apiWeatherData = getApiWeatherData();
    if(null != apiWeatherData.getCurrently()){
        CurrentlyPojo currently = apiWeatherData.getCurrently();
        if(null != currently){
            populateWeatherData(currently);
        }
    }
}

WeatherApiResponsePojo getApiWeatherData(){
   return WeatherDataSingleton.getInstance().getApiWeatherData();
}
```

then in your test expect that new method to return certain object:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestCurrentMoreInfoDataProvider {


    private CurrentMoreInfoDataProvider dataProvider;
    @Mock
    CurrentMoreInfoInterface.modelToPresenter modelToPresenter;
    @Mock
    WeatherApiResponsePojo apiWeatherDataMock;

    private CurrentlyPojo currentlyPojo = new CurrentlyPojo();
    @Test
    public void testPopulateWeatherData(){

        dataProvider = PowerMockito.spy(new CurrentMoreInfoDataProvider(modelToPresenter));

        doReturn(apiWeatherDataMock).when(dataProvider).getApiWeatherData();

        dataProvider.provideData();
        Mockito.verify(dataProvider).populateWeatherData(currentlyPojo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get following error

Wanted but not invoked:
currentMoreInfoDataProvider.populateWeatherData(

Comment: You have tell mockito what it should return when apiWeatherData.getCurrently() method is called. ApiWeatherData is a mock so just use when().thenReturn() to specify that

Comment: When I attempted first I did get the same error so to solve this I referred to
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/powermock/CEdP24sb_HY