# Mock Static Instance

Tags: mockito, powermockito

```
class Continents{

    Map<String,String> COUNTRY_CURRENCY_MAP = Singleton.getInstance().getCountryCurrencyMap()

}
```

I am trying to mock Singleton class using power mockito but I am not able to do it.

```
Continents continents = mock(Continents.class);
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Continents.class);
when(Continents.getInstance()).thenReturn(continents);
        when(continents.getCountryCurrencyMap()).thenReturn(new HashMap<String, String>());
```

But I am facing the following issue -

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassObject(Desc.java:43)
    at javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassType(Desc.java:152)
    at javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:122)
    at javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:78)
```

Comment: If any of the answers resolved your issue, please accept click the check mark to the left near the up and down arrows to accept.

If you are still having trouble I can look further if you edit your question to answer the question I asked in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about mocking this field `COUNTRY_CURRENCY_MAP` in your test instead of

```
Continents continents = mock(Continents.class);
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Continents.class);
when(Continents.getInstance()).thenReturn(continents);
        when(continents.getCountryCurrencyMap()).thenReturn(new HashMap<String, String>());
```

You may replace with

```
Continents continents = PowerMockito.spy(new Continents());
HashMap COUNTRY_CURRENCY_MAP = PowerMockito.mock(HashMap.class);
Whitebox.setInternalState(continents, "COUNTRY_CURRENCY_MAP", COUNTRY_CURRENCY_MAP);
```

Comment: Thanks @pyramidPeak

Answer (score 2):

Did you include the annotations?

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassWithStatics.class)
```

[See this Q&A for related details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583202/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object).

Another approach is not to use PowerMock at all: You can create a service which wraps the singleton and mock that with plain Mockito. See some example code for [the wrapper pattern here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29841824/3931488).