# Powermockito java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, exception, powermock, powermockito, verifyerror

I am using powermock.mockstatic this line blow so that I can control its returning value since its only swing I dont have to test it.

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
RelatedIntelligencePanel  rel = Mockito.mock(RelatedIntelligencePanel.class);
PowerMockito.mockStatic(RelatedIntelligencePanel.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(RelatedIntelligencePanel.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(rel);
...
.. some other unrelated code
}
...........
........ some other code and Tests
......
@Test
public class SomeClass{
RelatedIntelligencePanel relIntPanel = new RelatedIntelligencePanel();
```

But it throws java.lang.VerifyError. I did plenty of mocking this kind of thing and there was no exception like that. Removing @PrepareForTest and @Runwith helps but I lose powermock when I do that. My detailed error is also below ;

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
Location:
javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalLookAndFeel.getLayoutStyle()Ljavax/swing/LayoutStyle @3: areturn
Reason:
Type 'javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalLookAndFeel$MetalLayoutStyle' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'javax/swing/LayoutStyle' (from method signature)
Current Frame:
bci: @3
flags: { }
locals: { 'javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalLookAndFeel'}
stack {'javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalLookAndFeel$MetalLayoutStyle'}
Bytecode:
0x0000000: b807 49b0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. Using both `@PowerMockIgnore("javax.swing.*")` and

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassWithStatics.class);
when(ClassWithStatics.getString()).thenReturn("Hello!");
```

did solve my problem. `PowerMockito.when` won't work without `@PowerMockIgnore("javax.swing.*")` and reverse is also true. Both @stuXnet and @staszko032 was correct but those advices didn't work alone. Note : WhenNew is also working but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There [seems to be a problem](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/383) with Powermock, `@PrepareForTest` and static methods.

Does annotating your test class with `@PowerMockIgnore("javax.swing.*")`, as commented [on GitHub](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/383#issuecomment-124560231), help?

Comment: I also tried -noverify and -XX:-UseSplitVerifier but both didnt help too. If there is nothing I can do I might have to refactor the class so that I don't have to use PowerMockito but Its too much work so I want to avoid doing so.

Comment: Can you provide a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/)? This would be of great help nailing this problem down.

Comment: Other then what I wrote at my example only thing I can tell is I use @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) and @PrepareForTest({AccessServiceUtil.class, RelatedIntelligencePanel.class}) and In my code above staticMocked classes are not even using AccesServiceUtil.

Comment: But I tried to add more details to my code. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is no how you should mock a static with PowerMockito.

See this snippet ([PowerMockito mock single static method and return object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583202/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object))

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassWithStatics.class);
when(ClassWithStatics.getString()).thenReturn("Hello!");
```

As you want to mock static method, you shouldn't use whenNew construction, maybe it leads to your error.

Comment: Since I am trying to mock some new creation I have to use whenNew with noArgs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different problem. I saw error complaining about a class in javax.net.* so I added javax.net.* to @PowerMockIgnore(...), and it resolved the issue for me. It seems as if you could simply ignore the problem package, and that will resolve your issue.