# Mock variable in unit test android

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-testing

Searched on google about, how to mock a variable in unit testing and seen some suggestions, for my case its not working. my scenario is,

```
class Keys {

private static Keys sKeys;
private String enKey = null;

static synchronized sKeys getInstance() {
    if(sKeys == null) {
        sKeys = new Keys();
    }
    return sKeys;
}

Boolean isLocked() {
    if(enKey == null ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is the class, i have written. Unit test of the class is below,

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)     
public class KeysTest {

@Test
public void isLocked_Test() {
    Keys key = Keys.getInstance();
    Key.isLocked();
   // Here in isLocked function I want to mock the enKey value to other than null
   }
}
```

Here, i want to call isLocked function, and i want to set or mock the **enKey** variable value to other than null.

How i can do that?
Could anyone help me on that?

Answer (score 2):

To mock a static you will need to use [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock) or a similar library.

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583202/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object) question and answer.

Alternatively you could use the method described below after refactoring out the static design (if desired).

To create a mock using Mockito,

```
MyClass myMock = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
```

To set the return value of a specific function for a mocked class,

```
when(myMock.myFunc()).thenReturn(desiredValue);
```

Be sure to review the [documentation](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html) as well.

Comment: The example you said is not, myMock.myFunc() is not returning the mentioned value. and i don't want to mock a function. i want to mock the variable. This variable (enKey), i want to mock it as other than null.

Comment: If you are using Kotlin, the `when` statement is a reserved keyword so you need to surround it like: \`when\` with an import of `import org.mockito.Mockito.\`when\``