# Exception occurred when mock a class which having static method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I'm writing unit test (using TestNG) for a static method. When mocking the class of the static method I'm getting an exception.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TempClass.class)
public class MyTestClass {

  @Test
  public void testMethodt() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(TempClass.class);
  }
}

public class TempClass {

  public static String getName(String name){
    return "Hi " + name;
  }
}
```

When execute `PowerMockito.mockStatic(TempClass.class);` i'm getting following exception

```
org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException: 

[Ljava.lang.Object;@65466a6a
The class com.test.TempClass not prepared for test
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Take Care of Java naming conventions. Classnames should start with uppercase character

Comment: What is `com.aexistest.data.testClass`?

Comment: Are you using that mock? Did you configure the mock?

Comment: @Jens, it's a class having static method to test. testClass edited to TempClass

Comment: @Amadán, What configuration you mean?

Comment: @Nibras I am not so familiar with PowerMock, but usually a mock needs to be told, how to behave when methods are called - something that might look like: doReturn(x).when(mock).foo() (Mockito) or expect(mock.foo()).andReturn(x) (EasyMock). Some frameworks provide a default implemetation, others just give you an exception that might look like your's. Mind, that after configuring your mock you also might need to set that configuration active, like in EasyMock you need to call replay(mock) after configuration.

Comment: @Amadán as you mentioned i have configured the mock. but before that, i'm getting that exception

Comment: Is TempClass is your mockclass?if so have u created mock for TempClass. or you can call something like this in BeforeTest .mockStatic(TempClass.class)

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583202/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding following

```
@PrepareForTest(TempClass.class)
public class MyTestClass extends PowerMockTestCase {
   ....
}
```

Comment: Hint: all those things are very well documented, and they were asked here many times before. Sometimes you are much faster simply doing a bit of research, instead of putting up the 10th repetition of the same problem here ;-)