# How to mock a private method called from inside the constructor

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

I have a final class and want to test the catch block code through JUnit test cases. But I am not sure how can I mock the `returnObject()` which is being called inside the constructor, such that it throws `SomeException`. I used PowerMockito `@Spy` but in vain. I tried making the code inside `returnObject()` but the code is in such a manner that I cannot mock them to throw an exception. So the only option I have is to use spy the `returnObject()` to throw an exception.

```
public final class MyClass{
  public MyClass(){
    try{
      returnObject();
  }
 catch(SomeException se){
  //Logic which needs to be Junit tested
 }
}
private SomeObjectClass returnObject() throws SomeException{
   return <StaticMethodCall of another class>;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you read this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583202/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object ?

Comment: Do not mock the private method, instead pass data in that actually causes the exception. Why *does* it cause an exception in the first place? Is there not an external dependency that is called which actually causes the exception, you should mock that dependency.

Comment: tl;dr don't mock private things, period. They're implementation details. Test API.