# Mock a single static method using PowerMock and TestNG

Tags: java, mocking, testng, powermock

```
class StaticClass {
  public static String a(){ return "a"; }
  public static String ab(){ return a()+"b"; }
}
```

I want to mock `StaticClass::a` so that it returns `"x"` and the call to `StaticClass.ab()` results in `"xb"`...

I find it very hard in PowerMock and TestNG...

---

the exact code I am testing righ now:

```
class StaticClass {
    public static String A() {
        System.out.println("Called A");
        throw new IllegalStateException("SHOULD BE MOCKED AWAY!");
    }

    public static String B() {
        System.out.println("Called B");
        return A() + "B";
    }
}

@PrepareForTest({StaticClass.class})
public class StaticClassTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

    @Test
    public void testAB() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.spy(StaticClass.class);
        BDDMockito.given(StaticClass.A()).willReturn("A");
        assertEquals("AB", StaticClass.B()); // IllegalStateEx is still thrown :-/
    }

}
```

---

I have Maven dependencies on:

```
<artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
and
<artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
```

Comment: Did you try to do like in [PowerMock documentation](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/TestNG_usage) described?

Comment: @sigito YES! I will update the example to show you the code I need to mock

Comment: You must have lost `mockStatic` method call.

Comment: @sigito See, I don't want to mock **entire class** but just **a single static method**...

Answer (score 10):

Why not try something like :

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticClass.class);
Mockito.when(StaticClass.a()).thenReturn("x");
Mockito.when(StaticClass.ab()).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Comment: He's using TestNG and not Mockito.

Comment: what if, the method returns nothing (void), is this still possible? how about my static class has 20 static methods and I only want to mock one of the methods?

Comment: @Marquez yes, it's still possible for void method. In case the ab() is a void method which returns nothing, it could be like this: PowerMockito.when(StaticClass.class, "ab").thenCallRealMethod();

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be accomplished with a Partial Mock.

```
PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(Mocked.class, "methodToBeMocked");
```

This might be of help: http://avricot.com/blog/index.php?post/2011/01/25/powermock-%3A-mocking-a-private-static-method-on-a-class

Comment: This sounds ok. To be honest though, I very much **dislike specifying a method ... by string name**... This would be a horror to maintain w/o a good IDE. Any way to mock by writing actual Java code (in other words: mock just like an ordinary method)?

Comment: That is a good point. I think you can also accomplish this with a spy. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860475/powermock-mocking-of-static-methods-return-original-values-in-some-particula#answer-5063228