# Stub only one private static method in a class

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito, powermock

I have a class that I am unit testing. It looks like following:

```
 public class classToUT {
         public static Event getEvent(String id) {
                return getEvent(id, null);
         }
         private static Event getEvent(String id, String name) {
              //do something
              logEvent(id, name);
              return event;
         }
         private static void logEvent(String id, string name) {
             // do some logging
         }
    }
```

There are external util methods being called in `logEvent` that I want to avoid. Basically, I want only `logEvent` to be stubbed out but all other methods to be called in my unit test. How do I stub out this one method only?

```
public void UTClass {
    @Test
    public void testGetEvent() {
         assertNotNull(event, classToUt.getEvent(1)); //should not call logEvent 
        //but call real method for getEvent(1) and getEvent(1, null)  
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860475/powermock-mocking-of-static-methods-return-original-values-in-some-particula

Comment: While the above works for returning a value, I can't figure out a way for it to make it work for do nothing()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following ...

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(PowerTest.ClassToUT.class)
public class PowerTest {

    public static class ClassToUT {

        public static String getEvent(String id) {
            return getEvent(id, null);
        }

        private static String getEvent(String id, String name) {
            // do something
            logEvent(id, name);
            return "s";
        }

        private static void logEvent(String id, String name) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetEvent() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.spy(ClassToUT.class);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(ClassToUT.class, "logEvent", any(), any());

        Assert.assertEquals("s", ClassToUT.getEvent("xyz"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Golden stuff here